# AutoCompleteTextView not showing drop down menu - Android

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, autocompletetextview

I've followed material.io to build an "Exposed Dropdown Menus" but the drop down menu is not showing.

I want to achieve this:
[Dropdown (screenshot from material.io)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1cBy.jpg)

However, I'm currently getting this: [Failed dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGpma.png)

I'm not sure why I can even type into the box when I've added "android:inputType="none"" to the AutoCompleteTextView.

This is how I initialised the adapter inside the fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false);

    // Initialise drop down list
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            getContext(),
            R.layout.dropdown_menu_popup_item,
            UNITS
    );

    AutoCompleteTextView unitsExposedDropdown = view.findViewById(R.id.unit_selection);
    unitsExposedDropdown.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit: This is the link I'm using to build the Exposed Dropdown Menu https://material.io/develop/android/components/menu

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61581239/7434090

Comment: Alright that solved the issue of being able to type. However, the drop down is still not there. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> dont want to type in the box

then why don't you use popup menu see this:

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(youractivity.this, yourbutton);  
                //Inflate the pop up menu
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popmenu, popup.getMenu());  
  
                //do something on click 
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {  
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  
                      //do your work here
                    }  
                });  
  
                popup.show();//show it
```

To understand more see this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu

Comment: I prefer using the exposed drop down menus if possible.